Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Ethernet connection not working
I've just installed Ubuntu for the first time. Everything was working fine, but then I needed to add the VPN from my university. Since it didn't work I followed the recommended steps:

Check Networkmanager by sudo NetworkManager --print-config


Make sure that [ifupdown] is set to false
Check that you have the line dns=default
If not, change the NetworkManager.conf file and add in the main [main] section the line dns=default by sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf


Disable systemd-resolve for letting NetworkManager completely manage the network connections



sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved



sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved



sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf



sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager



Now my ethernet connection stopped working, and there is a question mark on the 'Wired Conncections' symbol.
If I go to 192.168.0.1, I can access my router's page.
If I ping 8.8.8.8, I get 0% packet loss.
I'm not sure what else to share, please help.

You don’t need to stop/disable systemd-resolved nor delete /etc/resolv.conf. You’ve effectively disabled your DNS resolver. I recommend returning your system to its default configuration and get the network functioning again without the VPN. Then, let’s get the VPN working by detailing your setup. If your run into issues, show us the error messages and describe the problem.

@mpboden How should I return my system to its 'default configuration'? Any guide you can suggest me? Do you mean formatting my PC? I'm new on Linux.

I would reverse all the steps you’ve taken thus far. If that’s not a possibility, then reinstalling would be the easiest solution.

Thank you! The solution was just:

sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved


The solution was just:


sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved 



sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved



Still no clue what I'm doing, but it worked.
Thanks to @mpboden!
